# Does decoding a bytestring using 'iso-8859-1' ever raise UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, iso-8859-1

I have some code where I'm dealing with an HTTP header.
I know that the header value *should* be in the ISO-8859-1 encoding,
although I want to ensure the program behaves gracefully in the event that it is not.

Initially I wrapped the decode in a `try..catch` for `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
try:
    value = header.decode('iso-8859-1')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    ...
```

However when I came to testing this behavior I wasn't able to simulate the error condition. Bytes which are not defined as being in [the iso-8859-1 codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) appear to still decode successfully.

```
>>> b'\x80'.decode('iso-8859-1')
u'\x80'
```

So:

- Can I avoid making using the `try..catch` and assume that it'll always successfully return a unicode string?
- Is the expected behavior of `.decode('iso-8859-1')` wrt out-of-codepage bytes likely to be platform specific or not?
- Is there a reproducible case where `UnicodeDecodeError` *is* raised by this code?

**Note**: Tested against both Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: In ISO-8859-1 encoding all byte values are legal, so no it won't.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks.

Comment: Found buried in the [History section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#History) of the Wikipedia article on ISO/IEC 8859-1 you referenced where it says in part: "...This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values _thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value_ [italics added]." Also note the C0 control set defines codes in the range 0x00–0x1F and the C1 set defines codes in the range 0x80–0x9F.

Comment: "thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value" <-- Perfect - thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it won't give you problems:

```
In [1]: for i in xrange(9999):
   ...:     chr(i).decode('iso-8859-1')
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c3c072235f24> in <module>()
      1 for i in xrange(9999):
----> 2     chr(i).decode('iso-8859-1')
      3 

ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```